# Purpose of having custom annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Some projects using of custom annotations as below. For example as below. Please explain me

1. when should I take decision to have custom annotations.
2. Role of @Target & @Retention annotation attributes
3. is it better to use import java.lang.annotation.Target and import java.lang.annotation.Retention or hibernate specific annotations as below

   @Entity
    @Table(name = "creditCard")

   **@CreditCardEntity**

   ```
   public class CreditCard implements java.io.Serializable {}

   import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
   import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
   import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
   import java.lang.annotation.Target;
   import org.hibernate.validator.ValidatorClass;

   @Target( { ElementType.TYPE })
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface CreditCardEntity {}

    }
   ```

Comment: Have you read this [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation)? "@Target - Marks another annotation to restrict what kind of Java elements the annotation may be applied to" and "@Retention - Specifies how the marked annotation is stored—Whether in code only, compiled into the class, or available at runtime through reflection."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you plan to use the same annotations together on more than one place in your code, it's a good idea to use custom annotations. For example, in your case, if you will use `@Entity @Table(name = "creditCard")` together in another place, it's a good idea to unite them under one annotation like the `CreditCardEntity` annotation, **but if that's the only place you will use those two annotations together (which is more likely in this case), it's unnecessary to make a custom annotation for it.**

Comment: Why would you ever want to have 2 entity classes that have the same name for the table? Not really viable example.

Comment: @Vaelyr If you read my answer carefully, I mentioned that it's not logical in this example as follows: 
**but if that's the only place you will use those two annotations together (which is more likely in this case), it's unnecessary to make a custom annotation for it.**